# Which Flutter default plugins are important?

Tags: flutter, plugins

I am relatively new to flutter and app development. I noticed that whenever a new flutter project is created, there are many default plugins pre-loaded into the project and this makes the app take up a minimum of 80 Mb. Could i get a summary on which plugins are actually important in order to run any app in general?

Comment: please see edit for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter provides almost all the basic things like themeing, icons, routing etc out of the box.

You can have any other package if you need more functionality like fetching data from internet and so on.

The important thing is the size you see is the debug build which is large as it contains the VM for hot reload to work at such speed. When you build the `release` version it is the minimum version which goes for about <5Mb on bare-bone app.

Currently my debug app stands at around 80mb on emulator but the release version is < 6mb.

So to answer your question,

1. it is the debug size,not the final version
2. Flutter requires no extra plugin for an offline app with basic functionality. Core components + testing is provided out of the box.
3. Nothing useless is shipped by default,

**NOTE**: there is a section called `dev_dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml` which means the packages listed under this won't go into the release build and are only for development purpose.